# Why does this namespaced route fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

Here's the route:

```
namespace :admin do
    get 'statistics', to: 'dashboard#statistics', as: :statistics
end
```

Here's the routing spec:

```
it 'routes to #statistics' do
    expect(get: '/admin/statistics').to route_to 'admin/dashboard#statistics'
end
```

It passes perfectly.

However, this controller spec, that uses the above route, fails:

```
RSpec.describe Admin::DashboardController, :type => :controller do
    let(:user){ FactoryGirl.create :user }
    let(:admin){ FactoryGirl.create :admin }

    describe '#statistics:' do
        let(:request){ get :statisitcs }

        context 'When guest;' do
            before { request }      

            describe 'response' do
                subject { response }    

                its(:status){ should eq 302 }
                its(:content_type){ should eq 'text/html' }
                it{ should redirect_to 'new' }
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is:

```
1) Admin::DashboardController#statistics: When admin; response content_type 
     Failure/Error: let(:request){ get :statisitcs }
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"statisitcs", :controller=>"admin/dashboard"}
```

But doesn't the routing spec prove that such a route exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your request is misspelled in the controller spec?

```
let(:request){ get :statisitcs }
```

Should be

```
let(:request){ get :statistics }
```

Based on the request spec and the route definition.  Its showing up as misspelled in the failed test as well, so...